# truncate shell command output from last line matching a string until EOF

Tags: linux, shell, awk, tail

I would like to truncate the output of a shell script and only print the part between the last line matching a string/regex and EOF.

E.g when running letsencrypt `certbot renew --post-hook "service apache2 reload; service nginx reload"` I get something like

```
...
http-01 challenge for domain1.tld
Waiting for verification...
Cleaning up challenges

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
new certificate deployed without reload, fullchain is
/etc/letsencrypt/live/domain1.tld/fullchain.pem
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Processing /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/domain2.tld
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Renewing an existing certificate
Performing the following challenges:
http-01 challenge for domain.tld
http-01 challenge for www.domain2.tld
Waiting for verification...
Cleaning up challenges

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
new certificate deployed without reload, fullchain is
/etc/letsencrypt/live/domain2.tld/fullchain.pem
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
** DRY RUN: simulating 'certbot renew' close to cert expiry
**          (The test certificates below have not been saved.)

Congratulations, all renewals succeeded. The following certs have been renewed:
  /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain1.tld/fullchain.pem (success)
  /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain2.tld/fullchain.pem (success)
  /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain3.tld/fullchain.pem (success)
  /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain4.tld/fullchain.pem (success)
** DRY RUN: simulating 'certbot renew' close to cert expiry
**          (The test certificates above have not been saved.)
Running post-hook command: service apache2 reload; service nginx reload
Output from service:
 * Reloading web server apache2
 * 
 * Reloading nginx configuration nginx
   ...done.
```

Now what I want to have is everything after the last `-------` line, so the desired result would be

```
** DRY RUN: simulating 'certbot renew' close to cert expiry
**          (The test certificates below have not been saved.)

Congratulations, all renewals succeeded. The following certs have been renewed:
  /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain1.tld/fullchain.pem (success)
  /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain2.tld/fullchain.pem (success)
  /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain3.tld/fullchain.pem (success)
  /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain4.tld/fullchain.pem (success)
** DRY RUN: simulating 'certbot renew' close to cert expiry
**          (The test certificates above have not been saved.)
Running post-hook command: service apache2 reload; service nginx reload
Output from service:
 * Reloading web server apache2
 * 
 * Reloading nginx configuration nginx
   ...done.
```

I thought about some `tail -n 15` command but I don't want to adjust my script each time I add a new domain.

Thanks for your help!

---

**Edit**: In the meantime I found a solution on my own which is not as nice as @anubhava's

```
cnt1=`grep -n "\----" certbot.log | tail -n1 | awk -F : '{ print $1 }'`
cnt2=`wc -l certbot.log | awk '{ print $1 }'`
cnt3=$((cnt2-cnt1))
tail -n $cnt3 certbot.log
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `awk` for this:

```
awk '/^-{6}/{p=1; str=""; next} p{str = str $0 ORS} END{printf "%s", str}' file
```

This awk command matches `------` as starting text in any line and once it finds it we set a flag `p` to `1` and initialize a buffer `str` to empty. Next we keep adding each line into buffer `str` if flag `p` is set.

Note that if we encounter another `------` then we reinitialize `str` to empty hence keeping lines from only last matched occurrence.

**Output:**

```
** DRY RUN: simulating 'certbot renew' close to cert expiry
**          (The test certificates below have not been saved.)

Congratulations, all renewals succeeded. The following certs have been renewed:
  /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain1.tld/fullchain.pem (success)
  /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain2.tld/fullchain.pem (success)
  /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain3.tld/fullchain.pem (success)
  /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain4.tld/fullchain.pem (success)
** DRY RUN: simulating 'certbot renew' close to cert expiry
**          (The test certificates above have not been saved.)
Running post-hook command: service apache2 reload; service nginx reload
Output from service:
 * Reloading web server apache2
 *
 * Reloading nginx configuration nginx
   ...done.
```

---

**Alternative solution** is to use `tac` before and after `awk` and print only first match:

```
tac file | awk '/^-{6}/{exit} 1' | tac
```

Comment: BTW your solution only works with `gawk` not with `mawk`

Comment: I have tested it on OSX that is BSD awk and it worked fine there as well. May be `mawk` doesn't like `/^-{6}/`, you can use: `/------/` there.

Comment: jep! That's it. Nice. Thank you :)